# Using KMeans tflearn estimator as part of a graph in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, k-means, tflearn

I am trying to use `tensorflow.contrib.learn.KMeansClustering` as part of a graph in Tensorflow. I would like to use it as a component of a graph, giving me predictions and centers. The relevant part of the code is the following:

```py
with tf.variable_scope('kmeans'):
    kmeans = KMeansClustering(num_clusters=num_clusters,
                              relative_tolerance=0.0001)
    kmeans.fit(input_fn= (lambda : [X, None]))
    clusters = kmeans.clusters()

init_vars = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_vars, feed_dict={X: full_data_x})
clusters_np = sess.run(clusters, feed_dict={X: full_data_x})
```

However, I get the following error:

```py
ValueError: Tensor("kmeans/strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("sub:0", shape=(), dtype=int32).
```

I believe this is because KMeansClustering is a TFLearn estimator; which would be more akin to a whole graph than a single module. Is that correct? Can I transform it to a module of the default graph? If not, is there a function to do KMeans within another graph?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KMeansClustering Estimator uses ops from tf.contrib.factorization. The [factorization MNIST example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/examples/mnist.py) uses KMeans without an Estimator.

Comment: I've looked at your suggestion and the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeans) for the function. If I'm not mistaken, they only provide distances from inputs to centers and labels for every input. However, I'm looking for the centers themselves, any idea how to get them? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a public accessor. You could either average the points using the cluster assignments, or call `_create_variables` in a `variable_scople` with `reuse=True` (you'll have to wrap the original variable creation in a variable scope too).

Comment: I can see that _create_variables outputs centers, but I don't see how/when they are influenced by the input data. How do you use the variable_scope to do it?

Comment: The centers are stored in a variable which gets updated during training. So as long as you have a handle on the same variable you'll read the updates. So around the original/normal training call use `with variable_scope("kmeans_variables") as vs:`, then close the scope and re-open a `with variable_scope(vs, reuse=True):` and call `_create_variables` manually. If it doesn't complain about missing variables, you'll have a handle on the same ones k-means is updating. Note that this isn't a public API for k-means, so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

The KMeansClustering Estimator API builds its own `tf.Graph` and manage `tf.Session` by itself, so you don't need to run a `tf.Session` to feed values (that is done by `input_fn`), that's why the `ValueError` arise.

The correct usage of KMeansClustering Estimator is just:

```
kmeans = KMeansClustering(num_clusters=num_clusters,
                          relative_tolerance=0.0001)
kmeans.fit(input_fn=(lambda: [X, None]))
clusters = kmeans.clusters()
```

where `X` is a `tf.constant` input tensor that holds the values (e.g. define `X` as `np.array` and than use `tf.convert_to_tensor`). Here `X` is not a `tf.placeholder` that needs to be feed at a `tf.Session` run.

**Update for TensorFlow 1.4:**

Use `tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering` API to find cluster centers:

```
kmeans=tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering(num_clusters=num_clusters)
kmeans.train(input_fn=(lambda: [X, None]))
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers()
```

To predict centers for given features just use:

```
predictions = kmeans.predict(input_fn=(lambda:[another_X, None]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17002) is a approach to use **KMeans Clustering** using `tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering`. It tells that the solution is to delay the creation of input `Tensor(X)` by putting it inside the `input_fn` lambda, which will be invoked within `train()`. Then you won't get the above mentioned error.